# How to remove all labels on event handler click

Tags: java, loops, javafx, eventhandler

I have an event handler which I would like to clear all labels of result before printing the new labels. I would like to keep the other labels that are not of type result. The code is currently only clearing the last instance of result. What loop do I need to add?

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) { 
    listLayout.getChildren().removeAll(result);
    Collections.sort(listOfCars, ListYears.yearCom);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfCars.size(); i++) {
        newCarsListings = listOfCars.get(i).toString();
        result = new Label(newCarsListings);
        result.setTranslateX(20);
        result.setTranslateY(-40);
        listLayout.getChildren().addAll(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new `ArrayList` called deletes. loop through the children finding the labels that meet your standard. Add those labels to the deletes `ArrayList`. After the loop is finished use `listLayout.getChildren().removeAll(deletes);`.

Comment: This seems like a design flaw. One would think that instead of creating new `Labels` you would use `setText()` to update the `Labels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create the label "result" for every car you have in your `listOfCars`. So your first line `listLayout.getChildren().removeAll(result)` will only remove the last created Label. If you have 10 cars in your list, you will create 10 Label objects, but only the last one can be referenced via `result`.

If you want to remove all your created Labels (and no other controls), I suggest you introduce a subclass of `Label`:

```
class CarLabel extends Label {
    CarLabel(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
}
```

And then in your `handle` method:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    listLayout.getChildren().removeIf(CarLabel.class::isInstance);
    Collections.sort(listOfCars, ListYears.yearCom);
    for(Object o : listOfCars) {
        result = new CarLabel(o.toString());
        result.setTranslateX(20);
        result.setTranslateY(-40);
        listLayout.getChildren().add(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the subclass really necessary? You could just as easily call `removeIf(Label.class::isInstance)` if he wants to remove all the labels...

Comment: @Zephyr I don't know the rest of your code. This subclass is only neccessary if you have other ``Label`` objects in your ``listLayout`` which do not represent cars.

Comment: I'm not the OP. :) They just asked how to remove all labels; perhaps if they were clearer in the question we could give a more definitive answer.

Comment: I edited the description there, I have other labels in the layout which I would like to keep, adding the subclass worked. Thank you

Comment: @GearoidSheehan - if this answer solved your problem, please be sure to accept it by clicking the checkmark above.

Answer (score -1):

`removeAll(result)` will only remove the elements in `listLayout.getChildren()` that are matching an element from `result`.

Have a look at the official [documention for removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)

If you want to remove every element the list is containing use the `clear()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear-java.util.Collection-)

```
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) { 

                listLayout.getChildren().clear()
                // the list should be empty now
                Collections.sort(listOfCars, ListYears.yearCom);

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfCars.size(); i++) {

                newCarsListings = listOfCars.get(i).toString();

                result = new Label(newCarsListings);
                result.setTranslateX(20);
                result.setTranslateY(-40);

                listLayout.getChildren().addAll(result);

                }
            }
          });
```

Comment: @WUUGI the issue is that .clear() removes everything in the layout, including the buttons and textfields I wish to keep. I am attempting to remove only the instances of result, but using .removeAll(result) is only removing the last instance of result created

Comment: You should try to clarify your question then.